# Can I deploy a charms inside a virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, juju, kvm-virtualization

Can a Juju charm only be deployed inside a LXD container ?

As a user I mean: does juju integrate natively lxd (or docker containers) technology or can be possible to deploy a charm inside a Virtual Machine (or a physical machine) without containers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Juju supports deploying into a LXD container as an option. For example:

```
juju deploy mysql --to lxd:25
```

This will deploy mysql to a lxd container on machine 25 (assuming you have one.) If you're not explicit, Juju will use an entire physical machine, for example:

```
juju deploy mysql
```

That command will use up an entire physical machine. In the case of virtualization, if you're using VMWare or OpenStack as a cloud then that machine could possibly be a VM.

There currently is no option to deploy to a VM inside an existing machine, for most workloads LXD will be more performant and allow for more density.